# Switch statement containing less than equal to or greater than equal to

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, expression

I was trying a CodeWars easy challenge to calculate BMI and return a weight rating of Underweight - Obese. I was interested specifically on how I could implement this in a switch statement as I already submitted the If + If else variation.
Additionally, when does switch statement become more viable in terms of clean code/performance.

Initially I submitted the if else variation.

```
function bmi(weight, height) {
 let bmiCalc = (weight / (height*height));

if (bmiCalc <= 18.5){
 return 'Underweight';
if else (bmiCalc <= 25.0){
 return 'Normal';
if else (bmiCalc <= 30.0){
 return 'Normal';
else (bmiCalc > 30.0){
 return 'Obese';
 }
}
```

I wondered then how a switch statement might look so I tried

```
function bmi(weight, height) {
  let bmiCalc = (weight / (height * height));
  
  switch (bmiCalc){
      case (<= 18.5):
        return 'Underweight';
      case (<= 25.0):
        return 'Normal';
      case (<= 30.0):
        return 'Overweight';
      case (> 30.0):
        return 'Obese';
  }
}
```

Which ultimately spit out a unexpected token '<=' error.
Is it possible to have such expressions in a switch statement.

I also tried to put in
`case (bmiCalc <= 18.5){ return 'Underweight'}`

Based on my findings from other languages, I saw that this expression would not work for my desired test case. Thanks in advance, hopefully not too silly of a question.